# form process bar without jquery

Tags: javascript, css

```
<form id="form_Warpper" action="data.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
        <div id="table1">
                <div class="title_Warpper">
                <p> 1. </p>
                <label> I am sexy. </label>
                <div class="allQuestion"><?php for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){?><input type="radio" name="Dq[1]" value="<?=$i?>"> <?=$i?> <?php } ?></div>
                </div>
                <div class="radio_Warpper">
                <p> 2. </p>
                <label> I am wonderful. </label>
                <div class="allQuestion"><?php for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){?><input type="radio" name="Iq[1]" value="<?=$i?>"> <?=$i?> <?php } ?></div>
                </div>
                <div class="radio_Warpper">
                <p> 3. </p>
                <label> I am scary. </label>
                <div class="allQuestion"><?php for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){?><input type="radio" name="Hq[1]" value="<?=$i?>"> <?=$i?> <?php } ?></div>
                </div>
                <div class="radio_Warpper">
                <p> 4. </p>
                <label> I am timing. </label>
                <div class="allQuestion"><?php for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){?><input type="radio" name="Aq[1]" value="<?=$i?>"> <?=$i?> <?php } ?></div>
                </div>
</div>
<form>
```

my intention is when each question clicked it % on the progress bar , but i also dont wanted to use jquery is that possible ? but i have no idea how to start yet , but i have idea on want it to be like this check this  [my idea to make like link](http://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/ybvLB).

but it done by jquery , and i also have 100 question so each is 1% how do i start without jquery?

Comment: You use plain javascript.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp maybe this is a place where you could start..

Answer (score 0):

You don't even have a progress bar in your HTML yet, but when you do you are going to need a click event handler to fire off a function that was passed the value from the click and set the progress bar like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("progress")[0].setAttribute("value", $myValue);
```